# Number of ways to choose size $k$ subsets out of set of size $n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know how can I formulate the arguments below:

0) Choose 2 subsets (of size $k$) $A, B$ out of $n$ elements so that they are disjoint.

1) Choose 2 subsets (of size $k$) $A, B$ out of $n$ elements so that $|A \cap B| \leq 1$

2) Choose 2 subsets (size $k$) $A, B$ out of $n$ elements so that $|A \cap B| \leq 2$

3) Choose 2 subsets (size $k$) $A, B$ out of $n$ elements so that $|A \cap B| \leq 3$

I know how to choose size $k$ subsets, but I don't know how I can combine it with those rules.

Is the answer for the first one is $({n\atop k})3^k$? guess I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer $({n\atop k})3^k$ for the first question is wrong. Note that if $2k>n$ then it should be zero.

I assume that you are interested in the set $\{A,B\}$ (if you are considering the ordered couple $(A,B)$ then multiply the result by $2$).

We choose one set in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways and the second one in $\binom{n-k}{k}$, then we multiply the two numbers and we divide by $2$ (to avoid overcounting):
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\binom{n-k}{k}.$$

More generally, if we have to choose two sets $A$ and $B$ of size $k$ out of $n$ elements with $|A\cap B|=j<k$, the number of ways is
$$N(n,k,j):= \binom{n}{j}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\binom{n-j}{k-j}\cdot\binom{n-k}{k-j}.$$
where $\binom{n}{j}$ is the number of ways to choose the intersection $A\cap B$.

Now it should be easy to find the answers when $|A\cap B|\leq j$.

Comment: OK. Can you explain why we divide it by 2? like some example for overcounting?

Comment: We have to divide by two if you are interested in the couple $\{A,B\}$: If $n=4$ and $k=2$ then the formula gives $3$: $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$,  $\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$,  $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}$.